# Using same mutex in host app and dll

Tags: delphi, mutex

I have a multithreaded application which dynamically loads dlls (plugins). I have threads in DLL. Between host app and dll is my own SDK which purpose is to enable communication with dll plugins (library interface) and to define shared resources between host app and dlls (data structures, etc..).

Host app is creating a mutex object with WinAPI function CreateMutex and passing a THandle of created mutex to every dll I load.  When thread in DLL is changing common resources it uses mutex to protect it. As I said I am using WinAPI.Windows unit for calling CreateMutex and all other mutex related functions (Release etc..).

The idea is to make SDK cross-platform thus I am about to modify SDK and I would like to get rid off unit WinAPI.Windows and all Windows related stuff of course.

I included System.SyncObjs to use TMutex class. Now I am not quite sure how I would let know my dll's about that class. One option is to pass TMutex to my DLL but I think this is not an option if I want to keep primitve data types in my SDK because SDK must be available to other languages  such as C++, C#... etc  Other idea that crosses my mind is to use named mutexes and just pass a name (string) to DLL.

According to MSDN: *If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, bInitialOwner is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership. However, if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and the caller should use the OpenMutex function.*

So I assume DLL will be able to use existing named mutex (MyMutex) when it will call TMutex.Create(...,'MyMutex').

Am I right?

Thank you for your help and your suggestions. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can't pass a Delphi object from exe to dll, or vice versa. You'll need to use platform types. Rather than passing mutexes, may be better to use named mutexes.

Comment: You *can* pass a Delphi object if both exe and dll are compiled with runtime packages enabled.  I would stick with just passing `THandle`, though.  Or better, `Pointer` and let the exe/dll typecast it when needed.  Writing cross-platform code does not mean eliminating the `Windows` unit. You can `IFDEF` it so it is used only on Windows platforms.  Cross-platform code ultimately has to use platform-specific APIs, they are just hidden from public interfaces.

Comment: @Remy You can only do that if you use the same compiler version. It's not enough  just to enable runtime packages. What's more, you can only pass objects that are defined entirely in the packages. You can't have types declared in the exe or the dll

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Although possible, what you describe sounds to me like a disaster waiting to happen. There are too many things that have to be perfectly in place, so - at least for my taste - that is too much of a fragile construction. Especially as the OP said, that he wants to make the thing available to C++ and C#.

Comment: This is where I would choose interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a class instance between modules other than runtime packages is not allowed. That is not a valid form of interop.

So I think that the cleanest solution will be to wrap `TMutex` with an interface. You can pass interfaces between any type of module, even modules compiled by different compilers.

There are a variety of different mutexes available but in my view the obvious choice would be to wrap `TMonitor`. The interface is simple:

```
type
  IMutex = interface
    procedure Acquire; stdcall;
    procedure Release; stdcall;
  end;
```

It is perfectly safe to pass this interface between executables and DLLs.

The implementation might be as follows:

```
type
  TXplatMutex = class(TInterfacedObject, IMutex)
  public
    procedure Acquire; stdcall;
    procedure Release; stdcall;
  end;

procedure TXplatMutex.Acquire;
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(Self);
end;

procedure TXplatMutex.Release;
begin
  TMonitor.Exit(Self);
end;
```

You can wrap any mutex you like in this way. I opted for `TMonitor` because it is supported on all platforms and is the main tool used by Embarcadero library code for synchronization.

Comment: I am already using interfaces in my SDK and I haven't thought to use them for sharing  sync objects to dll. I guess I am just too long looking at same point. Sometimes is best to make a step back to see a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows mutexes can be "shared" across processes (and even more so in an exe and DLL) - you have two ways:

1. Use a named mutex. Use the OpenMutex() API to get the handle of an already existing mutex - you need to ensure it's called after CreateMutex() or it won't find the mutex to open.
2. Use DuplicateHandle() for an unnamed mutex, it returns a new handle valid in the target process (which can be the same, in the case of a DLL)

Often, the API wrapper in Delphi are too limited for "complex" scenarios. Using directly the Windows APIs will give you full access to the underlying functionalities, even if Delphi doesn't expose them. It turn, you will learn more about how Windows works, and it's a knowledge you can always recycle outside Delphi... and you don't need to use ugly hacks to wrap something that doesn't need to get wrapped in interfaces or the like...

If you need cross-platform capabilities, write your own wrappers for the OS mutex implementation - don't rely on the Delphi ones.

Comment: @Luigi Asker is already calling `CreateMutex`. Asker already has a Windows solution that works. Asker is trying to work out how to do the x-plat part. So all your text about not needing to wrap seems to miss the point. Your final paragraph gets it though.

Comment: Luigi thanks. Yes as David siad I already have a working solution for Windows. Now I am modifying my code to be as much as possible cross-platform friendly. I will have to do some wrappers, especially around sync objects. Now I share THandle var across my app and dll and this now works but I assume this is not the case when compiling for  MacOS. So somehow I have to get rid of that THandle (which is located in my SDK) var and do it differently, maybe even with different apporach to make it more universal.

Comment: @Heffernan: the problem with low-level system objects is that using them properly goes beyond just passing a Delphi instance wrapping them around - you need to be sure that what the other thread or process gets is *actually* and *properly* usable. You have to follow the OS semantic to create and pass around the proper "handles". If you fail to do so, sure, you get a Delphi working instance, but it can be a wrapper of the wrong sytem object. For example POSIX mutexes instatiation and usage is a bit different from Windows ones, you need to ensure each thread/process gets a proper mutex.